# JSON.stringify on column name when outputting to CSV

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have an API that pulls information from a database and then uses Javascript to output that data into a CSV:

```
    //Get Collection Info
    jQuery.getJSON(
    "https://db.staging.com/collection/downloadCollection.php,
    function(val) {  

        var json = val;
        var fields = Object.keys(json[0])
        var replacer = function(key, value) { return value === null ? '' : value } 
        var csv = json.map(function(row){
          return fields.map(function(fieldName){
            return JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)
          }).join(',')
        })
        csv.unshift(fields.join(',')) // add header column
         csv = csv.join('\r\n');

          var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
            hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
            hiddenElement.download = 'Card Collection.csv';
            hiddenElement.click();                           
    });
```

It works for the most part but I noticed a bug today with fields that contain `"` in their name.

For example, one field is `Spirit Message "N"` is output as `Spirit Message \A\""`

The line in question causing this is: `return JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)`

I've tried using JSON.parse which fixed the issue but then caused issues with fields that have `,` in their names. `return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer))`

How would I fix this so it correctly outputs as `Spirit Message "N"`?

Comment: You should provide an example of *val* that causes the issue. You might also reduce the code to a minimum, e.g. just the code in the function body down to `csv.unshift(…)`.

Comment: _“How would I fix this so it correctly outputs as `Spirit Message "N"`?”_ - by properly applying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules